# How do I get rid of the spacing between my navbar and slider?

Tags: html, css

There is a white space between my nav bar and the rest of the content on my page I am trying to figure out how to get rid of it. Here is an image of the issue as well.

Comment: If you can, please post the HTML for the navbar and some of the other content on the page, so that we can see the problem your experiencing.

Answer (score 0):

as MichaelvE said hard to know without seeing HTML...
You define space between nav li as margin and padding value so it should be that who set space at end of nav.
In that case you've to set margin and padding of last nav element(li?) to 0 or more acurately to margin-bottom:0; and padding-bottom:0; if the space is at bottom of nav (or left or right if you've space at left or right).

edit: you can see which element margin or padding will make unapropriate space by setting a test value as border:1px solid red; on nav and li (using a different color) and see where (in which element)the space is no wanted.